# Logic Gates - 3 Sensors in a Factory

Tags: logic, circuits

I am studying logic gates and I encountered this problem:

A set of three sensors in a factory detects whether the pollution level it is
outputting from an incinerator exceeds the safety limit. In which case the
incinerator is shut down. An alarm A goes off if at least two the three sensors
s1, s2 and s3 detect a pollution level above the limit. Draw a logic circuit for
the system showing the inputs s1, s2 and s3 and the output A.

[image]

I drew it with 3 AND gates, each AND gate covering two possibilities (s1,s2), (s2,s3) and (s1,s3) and all of them are connected to a single OR gate at the end. However, this is the suggested solution to the problem. Why do 2 OR gates exist here? Isn't one OR gate is sufficient?

Source: https://prezi.com/urw4nqm4ftfx/electronics/?fallback=1

Comment: Please credit the original source where you encountered this.  See our rules regarding copying material written by others (https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and [edit] your post to comply with those requirements.

Comment: @D.W. Added the source as requested.

Comment: How would you draw it with one OR gate?